# "Judge in so delicate and subtle a matter"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

[Source](https://books.google.jo/books?id=c4wolyWgqagC&pg=PA39&dq=can%20judge%20in%20so%20delicate%20and%20a%20matter%20i%20believe%20the%20chances&hl=ar&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0hdrx9_7VAhXIfxoKHdIFAsMQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=can%20judge%20in%20so%20delicate%20and%20a%20matter%20i%20believe%20the%20chances&f=false) Anna Karenina

- ... far as anyone can ***judge*** ***in*** so ***delicate*** and ***subtle*** a ***matter***, I believe the chances are..

I have some questions about this text.

First, how could a verb (judge) be separated from the direct object (a matter) by adjectives (subtle and delicate)

Second, as i know, after preposition comes a noun or gerund, but i have never seen a preposition followed by adjectives, how do you explain that?

Rather than, i would use the text in this way:

_ ... Judge a matter delicately and subtly.

Comment: **judge** there is used intransitively, complemented by a prepositional phrase headed by **in**, *in so delicate and subtle a matter*.  There is no direct object.  That is, to judge *in* a matter that is so delicate and subtle.

Comment: What does "matter" function? @Tᴚoɯɐuo a part of preposition phrase?

Comment: **matter** is the object of preposition **in**, not the object of the verb **judge**.

Comment: In a matter so delicate and subtle, it is not easy to judge.

Comment: **so delicate and subtle** can be placed  before or after **a matter**.

Comment: Is if it acceptable to put them after and before. Why it is not made one phrase such as: **a** delicate and subtle matter. Because the writer, put them separated from a matter. Look i changed the place of the determiner, (a) @Tᴚoɯɐuo

Comment: The word **so** expresses the *degree* of delicacy and subtlety. It implies that the matter is quite delicate and subtle.  Your version omits the notion of degree.

Comment: Only Superman could leap so tall a building. Only Superman could leap a building so tall.  A building of its (extreme) height can be leapt only by Superman. But maybe Batman could leap a tall building not quite so tall.

Answer (score 1):

> First, how could a verb (judge) be separated from the direct object (a matter) by adjectives (subtle and delicate)

As Tᴚoɯɐuo said, it's an indirect object, not direct. And there's nothing wrong with separating a direct object with adjectives, e.g. "Wear warm clothing".

> Second, as i know, after preposition comes a noun or gerund
>   "so delicate and subtle a matter" is a noun phrase; the whole phrase acts as a noun. Again, there's nothing wrong with putting an adjective between a preposition and its object, e.g. "Cut the apple into small pieces".

Answer (score 0):

My friend, I believe you're referring to **adverbs** rather than **adjectives**, like you mentioned "**delicately**".
Nevertheless, those two words, "**delicate**" and "**subtle**" aren't adverbs ironically, but adjectives!

I mean the sentence is absolutely correct, but the register is literary and thus a little sophisticated. Therefore, no wonder you're a little confused.

Let's paraphrase the sentence together:

*... as far as anyone cann judge in so delicate and subtle a matter, I believe the chances are..*:

In other words:

... as far as anyone can judge in **such a delicate and subtle matter**, I believe the chances are...

This sounds now more familiar, right?

I hope my comment is helpful.